# How does sorting of objects based on an attribute work?

Tags: sorting, abap

Let's say, I have an internal table `gt_table`, I got many entries with a field `INSTANCE`, the value of each field is a reference to a different object, each object comes from the same class, has the same attributes (`atribute_1`, `atribute_2`, `atribute_3`), but of course has different value. Now I want to sort the objects by the 3 attributes.

If it's possible as here:

```
SORT gt_table BY instance->atribute_1 instance->atribute_2 instance->atribute_3.
```

Looks yes, but how can this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with coding and internal table data.

Comment: After posting a minimal reproducible example, could you also clarify how your question differs from "how sorting works", I don't get your point, because sorting is a quite simple concept.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapsort_itab.htm), the following alternative is available for specifying components in the `SORT` statement:

> If the component has a reference type, the object component selector -> can be used to access all visible attributes attr of the referenced object. In this case, a table component can be specified more than once.

What is does is simply following the reference and using the value it points to for sorting. So instance1 in the first row might have `instance->atribute_1 = 3` and instance2 in the second row might have `instance->atribute_1 = 1`. When sorting ascending by `instance->atribute_1`, `1` will come first, then `3`.

Comment: That's the crystal answer, tks very much!  so it's like ABAP keyword SORT provides some algorithm internally to support this function logic if the field component is a reference data object to an object.  If this algorithm does not exist, it will raise an error. So to read the help document is super important to understand which kind of function is supporting the keywords.

Comment: @sisi The sorting algorithm will basically always exists, since it's implemented with the ABAP kernel. The only way you can influence it is to be stable (with `STABLE`) or a unstable one by default.